# Office.context.mailbox.item.body is not defined

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Office Addin for outlook, I struct with the following, please kindly help.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` method is working fine in Office 365 , but when it comes to on premise exchange server 2013, it works in outlook client but not works in outlook web app. Minimum mailbox requirement set version is 1.3

[image: issue]

Comment: Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` minimum mailbox requirement version is wet to **1.3** level API. In same time according to "[Understanding Outlook API requirement sets](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook#clients)" the Outlook Web App (Exchange 2013 On-Premise) supports only **1.1** level API.

Comment: In OWA Exchange 2013 On-Premise, is `Office.context.mailbox.item.body` not available? The spec says it is available from Mailbox 1.1

Comment: @AbhishekSJain `Office.context.mailbox.item.body` object is available in 1.1 level, but the methods of this object developed at different time as of the required level for `getAsync` is 1.3. As an example `prependAsync` available from 1.1 level API. Please refer to documentation link provided.

Comment: when I try using `Office.context.mailbox.item.body` in 1.1 version, I get `undefined`, I was trying to check whether `getAsync` is supported or not, by using `if (Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync !== undefined)`, apart from using `isSetSupported`, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @AbhishekSJain You don't have to check if function is available or not; your manifest defines level API you are requesting. What you asking is separate question you should ask community as your own question. In this question you need to provide a lot more information, such as version of client you are using, what is your Exchange environment; where do you call this function, etc. Sorry, this is beyond just comments to someone else question.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the email body in Office Mailbox API version 1.1 and above by calling the `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` method and making an ajax call to an EWS server. The example Microsoft provides is located at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.1#getcallbacktokenasync-callback--usercontext-

My working example:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, (result) => {
    var ewsId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
    var token = result.value;

    // var restId = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(ewsId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0); this does not work on API version 1.1
    var restId = ewsId.replaceAll("/", "-").replaceAll("+", "_"); // Convert ewsId to restId
    var getMessageUrl = (Office.context.mailbox.restUrl || 'https://outlook.office365.com/api') + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + restId;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', getMessageUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Prefer', 'outlook.body-content-type="html"') // for retrieving body as HTML
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.onload = (e) => {
      var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var emailBody = json.Body.Content;
    }
    xhr.send();
  });
```